# Using Overlay UI button in Google VR

Tags: user-interface, uiview, virtual-reality, google-vr

I'm trying to work with Google VR (GVR) newest versions. I want to add a normal Canvas Button to my scene so that users can touch the button to go back to previous scene our trigger some action. I tried adding a normal overlay button to my scene but it doesn't show up in the build. I wanted to ask if you guys have any solutions to that
Thanks